# NUMERİCAL METHOD Trapezoidal Rule Fails When N=3 WHY?

Tags: matlab

```
clc
clear all
close all
f=@(x) (exp(3*x)+sin(x));
x0=pi/2;
xn=pi;
%x0=input('lower= ');
%xn=input('upper= ');
N=input('N= ');
h=((xn-x0)/N);
area =0;
while (x0<xn)
   area=area+(h/2)*(f(x0)+f(x0+h));
   x0=x0+h;
end
fprintf('area=%f',area);
```

Everything is okey in this code without entering the N value as 3. There is a fail why?

Comment: no fail for me...

Comment: When N=3 area must be 4903.4028 but matlab shows 23753.1922

Comment: when you say fail it means the code breaks not that the numerical accuracy is bad.

Comment: all the N values except 3 is true for this code. There is problem with 3. I am asking that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
% ...
N = input('N= ');
h = (xn-x0) / N;
area = 0;

for i=1:N
    area = area + ((h/2) * (f(x0) + f(x0+h)));
    x0 = x0 + h;
end

fprintf('area=%f',area);
```

and now it's time to explain you why.

Since you are dividing the difference between `xn` and `x0` by `N`, the number of loops needed in order to obtain `x0 = xn` are equal to `N` because at the end of every loop you do `x0 = x0 + h`. If `N = 3`, you automatically know that after the third loop you will need to stop since `x0 = xn`.

Using a `while` and comparing `x0` and `xn` is dangerous, since they are both double precision floating-point numbers and they may loss precision during the iterations. There is the possibility that they will not match even if they are very very very very very very very ... very close to each other.

Using your approach, due to loss of precision, after the third loop you will have `x0` and `xn` almost identical... well, identical if you round them up to like 10 digits or so, but not exactly identical on a higher precision after the decimal dot... so your `while` condition will fail and the loop will continue.

If you want to perform a good comparison between to floating-point numbers keeping a high precision profile you need to check for:

```
abs(a - b) > eps(max(abs(a), abs(b)))
```

like (this `while` can do the job within your code):

```
while (abs(xn - x0) > eps(max(abs(xn), abs(x0))))
    %...
end
```

In other words, you have to define a `tolerance level`.